# Checking contents of a file before it was modified in linux

Tags: linux

I wanted to know if there was any way to check the contents of a file before it was modified in linux. 
As in suppose i have a file called example.cpp where i have a C++ code written in it. Now if i made some changes and saved it, is it possible to check the older example.cpp file without the changes made?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is what version control is for.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible. Linux does not store versioned copies of files.

What you can do is store your source files in a source control system such as `git`, `subversion` or `cvs`. These provide full versioning of all files stored within their repositories.

Answer (score 0):

The file system does not make backups or do versioning. However, some editors make backups before saving. At least Gedit saves a backup of `example.cpp` as `example.cpp~`.

Comment: cant we look at only the changes made atleast?

Comment: If you have an old version to compare with, then use your favourite compare tool, like `diff file1 file2` or `meld file1 file2`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to accomplish your goal:

1. Use a [versioning file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning_file_system#Linux). Then what you want to do happens automatically.
2. Use a VCS, such as Subversion, Mercurial or Git, and commit after (resp. before) every change.